# how to get first and other random rows from a table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table with 10 rows.  I want to get first and any 3 random rows.  Is it possible to do in one query?

Thanks,
   aby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1 --First row
UNION
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Foo ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1)
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
```

Of course, you may want to not select the first row in the random part, but you said ANY 3

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this at the app layer, as you can introduce caching later. Plus it's much faster to do random operations within the application than is at the database layer.

```
// Your database stuff

while ($row = $result->fetchRow()) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

$firstResult = array_shift($results);

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++) {
    $randomKey = array_rand($results);
    $randomResults[] = $results[$randomKey];
}

echo $firstResult;

foreach ($randomResults as $randomResult) {
    echo $randomResult;
}
```

Comment: That highly depends on how many rows are in that table. If you have only ten or twenty rows, caching might be a good idea. But given the table consists of 100 000 rows? You wouldn't want to transfer them all through the data base connection only to get four of them.

Comment: But you don't have to fetch all the results, but just the three ones chosen by the random function. Then, LIMIT could be used to select exactly these rows.

Comment: Understood. There are alternate solutions for large result sets, which are not handled at the database layer. Even if you put a limit qualifier in your sql, MySQL still does an entire table copy to do the order by.